# Jumping a certain amount of time in html5 video using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing out Selenium's html5 video automation methods, I can't find one to jump a certain amount of time for current location in the video.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_I4zqC7GN8")
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].currentTime=30
```

allows me to jump to the 30-second time mark.

However, I want to jump 30-seconds from my current time position.

Most tutorials are in java, with some getting really deep into java code -- I'm unfamiliar with Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add `30` to the current `currentTime` value:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].currentTime += 30;
```

Comment: Wow. That was simple. I noticed that this style attribute below is correlated with how much I move the time cursor. `<div class ="ytp-tooltip ytp-bottom" style "max-width: 300px; top: 405px; left: 142.5px; display: none;" data-layer ="4">` (youtube specific).  The numbers changes as I hover the mouse over the time bar. Would I be able to directly connect to this element and influence time this way, instead of relying on `executescript` method?  I tried, but I kept getting `NosuchElement` exceptions.

Comment: @Moondra I don't think changing `style` would work and you should do it with "execute script" - even though I have not done this before. Thanks, glad it worked.