# Getting error Cannot read property 'currentTime' of undefined when uexecute JavaScript using Selenium with Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I would like to jump to a specific time while playing a video. While I have manage to achieve similar objective from YouTube website (see thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61523738/6446053)), the same approach fail to work properly at a different website. As much I would like to share the website link, but due to confidential concern, Im unable to disclose it here.

The embedded video in this website have frame with the ID `player`. And I know the following line is working without any error.

```
        video = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "player")))
```

Since, the iframe does not have a `TagName`, I instead replace the `getElementsByTagName` into [`getElementById`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp). However, the compiler return an error

> Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'currentTime' of undefined

The full code is as below

```
   video = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "player"))) # The line work perfectly
    print('Fast forward')
    player_status = self.browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('player')[0].currentTime += 80;") # The compiler return an error at this line.
    print('Get Current time')
    time_video = self.browser.execute_script("return document.getElementById('player')[0].currentTime;")
```

I appreciate for any hint or help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no getElement**s**ById, there is `getElementById` *singular*. It returns a single element, not a collection.

Comment: Thanks for the response @vlaz. But, I got different error after changing it into singular. The new error is: Cannot read property 'currentTime' of undefined

Comment: Because *it returns a single element*! You are trying to get "the first" element from it `[0]`, this wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Appreciate it

Comment: For future reader> The line should be: 'player_status = self.browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('player').currentTime += 80;")'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by @VLAZ, the syntax should be changed into

```
self.browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('player').currentTime += 80;")'
```